# How can I make this function watch for changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

https://jsfiddle.net/1vm0259x/ I want to have it so when the contents of #b changes it immediately makes the div display. Is that possible? I'm having to get a little hacky because of the limitations of a CMS plugin. I don't know jQuery very well.

Markup

```
<div id="a">
    <span id="b">0 items</span>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if($('#b:contains("0 items")')) {
        $('#a').css("display", "none");
    }

    if($('#b:not(:contains("0 items"))')) {
        $('#a').css("display", "block");
    }

});
```

Answer (score -5, accepted):

You can't really "watch" something in JavaScript since it's an event-driven language (there are a few exceptions to this rule when it comes to object properties, but it is not something that is commonly useful).

Instead you should set an interval that updates regularly. I used 50 millisecond intervals, you can choose to use whatever interval you like:

```
function update() {

    if($('#b:contains("0 items")').length) {
        $('#a').css("display", "none");
    }

    if($('#b:not(:contains("0 items"))').length) {
        $('#a').css("display", "block");
    }

}

$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(update, 50);
});
```

Comment: Just be aware that short intervals that run forever can kill mobile battery life or cause browsers to slow-down or delay your timers (in the interest of preserving battery life).  Long term polling on such a short interval really isn't recommended.  Much better would be to find the actual code that changes the display or some event that might change the display and hook into that.  For example, if the display is only changed after an Ajax call, you can hook into Ajax calls and check the display after an Ajax call completes.

Comment: @jfriend00 I agree but without any more context it's hard to write my answer that way. This is the best I can recommend with so little information.

Comment: Except I don't think this is a recommended way to solve the problem.  I think the recommendation is to find a better way to solve the problem which would require more information.  FYI, the best StackOverflow answers seek out the best solution, even if it needs more information rather than an undesirable solution based on the information provided.

Comment: @jfriend00 then by all means ask OP for more information if you'd like to provide a better solution. Since OP says "I'm having to get a little hacky because of the limitations of a CMS plugin," I assume this is the sort of solution he is looking for.

Comment: I did file my own answer that doesn't use polling.

Answer (score 8):

The best way to monitor for text changes like this are to find a way to hook into some related and existing event in the browser and then see if the text has changed to what you want.

In the newer browsers (such as IE11+, recent versions of Chrome, Firefox and Safari), you can use a DOM `MutationObserver` to directly watch to see if the text nodes change.

The mutation callback is called anytime the children of the specified element are changed (children include the text nodes).

Here's some runnable code that watches for a text change in a div in this code snippet:

```js
document.getElementById("go").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var t = document.getElementById("test");
    t.innerHTML = parseInt(t.innerHTML, 10) + 1;    
});

var m = new MutationObserver(function(mRecords, obj) {
    log("Current text value: " + document.getElementById("test").innerHTML);
}).observe(document.getElementById("test"), {childList: true, characterData: true, subtree: true});

function log(x) {
    var d = document.createElement("div");
    d.innerHTML = x;
    document.body.appendChild(d);
}
```

```html
<button id="go">Click Me to Change the Text</button><br><br>
<div id="test">1</div><br><br>
```

---

If you need support for older version of IE, then the next best thing would be to figure out what existing events in the browser precede the text change and monitor those events.  When one of those events occurs, you can then check the text.  For example, if the action that triggers the text change always comes after an Ajax call, you can monitor/hook Ajax calls on a system wide basis and then check your text after each Ajax call completes.  Since this only ever does anything when other things are already happening in the web page, it's very efficient.  Or, if the text only changes after a particular button is clicked or some text field is changed, you can monitor those DOM elements with event listeners.

To suggest how to do that more specifically, we'd need to see the details of your actual circumstance and would have to understand what events in the page lead to the changing text.  Such short duration timers can also negatively affect the performance of things like animations running in your page or in other tabs.

---

It is NOT recommended to use a short duration timer to poll the DOM because this kills mobile battery life and, in fact, mobile browsers will attempt to delay or slow down any long running interval timers you use in order to try to preserve battery life.

Comment: @James - I offered an answer that does not use inefficient timer polling.

Comment: I agree with this answer, however, I will leave my answer since it was the "hack" James was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

On top of `MutationObserver`, eloquently put by @**jfriend00**, there is an older API available at our disposal as well by the name `DOMSubtreeModified`. Combine that with `onpropertychange` that of Internet Explorer and I believe you get a nice backward compatible *change* event. Take a look at the snippet below, not thoroughly tested though:

***Snippet:***

```js
var myDIV=document.getElementById('a');
var mySpan=document.getElementById('b');
var myButton=document.getElementById('button');
var myResult=document.getElementById('result');

if(window.addEventListener){
    myButton.addEventListener('click',onButtonClicked,false);
    mySpan.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified',onSpanModified,false);
}else{
    myButton.attachEvent('onclick',onButtonClicked);
    mySpan.attachEvent('onpropertychange',onSpanModified);
}

function onButtonClicked(){
    //mySpan.innerText=Math.random();
    mySpan.innerHTML=Math.random();
}

function onSpanModified(){
    myResult.innerHTML=mySpan.innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
    <span id="b">0</span>
</div>
<input id="button" type="button" value="Click Me" />
<span id="result"></span>
```

Hope this helps in some way though. Apologies if this was not what you were looking for and if I misunderstood your problem completely.